# Write file and read file in C

Tags: c, fopen

I am doing some homework and preparing for a final exam. Here is my problem:

> A square matrix (nxn)
>
> Write down the Even elements into matran.txt, then read from file and display it on screen

Code:

```
//this is function write down file matrix.txt, and it's work normally 
void infile(int **p,int n)
{
    bool a=false;
    FILE *f=fopen("matran.txt","w");
    if (f==NULL)
    {
        printf ("\nLoi file.");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if ((p[i][j]) % 2 == 0) {
          fprintf (f,"%d\t",p[i][j]);
          a=true;
        }
      }   
    if (a) printf ("\nFile da duoc ghi tai ./matrix.txt");
    else printf ("\nKhong co so chan trong ma tran");

}
```

I know that it's has a limit from `0->n` but I don't know what is limit of `i` and I tried set limit to 100 but it's still print out 3 values and it's display 100 diff address:

```
//but this didnt work
void DocTep(int **p, int n) {
  int *ptr=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
  FILE *f = fopen("matran.txt", "r");
  if (f == NULL) {
    printf("\nLoi file.");
    exit (1);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fscanf(f, "%d ",ptr[i]);
  }

  fclose(f);
  printf ("\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf ("%d\t",ptr[i]);
  }
}
```

**This is full program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void nhapmt (int **p,int n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
      scanf("%d", &p[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

void inmt (int **p,int n)
{
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    printf ("\n");
    for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        printf ("%d\t",p[i][j]);
    }
}
}

void tongcheo(int **p,int n)
{
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum += p[i][i];
    }   
    printf ("\nTong cac so tren duong cheo chinh la: %d",sum);
}

void tongh(int **p,int n,int h)
{
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum += p[i][h];
    }   
    printf ("Tong cot %d la: %d",h,sum);
}

void infile(int **p,int n)
{
    bool a=false;
    FILE *f=fopen("matran.txt","w");
    if (f==NULL)
    {
        printf ("\nLoi file.");
        exit(1);
    }
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if ((p[i][j]) % 2 == 0) {
        fprintf (f,"%d\t",p[i][j]);
        a=true;
    }
    }   
    if (a) printf ("\nFile da duoc ghi tai ./matran.txt");
    else printf ("\nKhong co so chan trong ma tran");

}


void DocTep(int **p, int n) {
    int *ptr=(int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));
  FILE *f = fopen("matran.txt", "r");
  if (f == NULL) {
    printf("\nLoi file.");
    exit (1);
  }
//    fscanf(f,"%d",&ptr[0]);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fscanf(f, "%d ",ptr[i]);
  }

    fclose(f);
    printf ("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("%d\t",ptr[i]);
}
}

int main()
{
    int **p,n,h;
    printf ("Hay nhap vao n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    p=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    p[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    }
    nhapmt(p,n);
    inmt(p,n);
    tongcheo(p,n);
    printf ("\nHay nhap vao h: ");
    scanf("%d",&h); 
    tongh(p,n,h);
    infile (p,n);
    DocTep(p,n);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Input n=`3` `2` `4` `6` `8`
in `matran.txt`: `2 4 6 8`
Output: `2 4 6 8`

Comment: Without knowing what the code that calls your code looks like, what's in the "matrix.txt" file, and what this function is intended to do, there's no way we can tell whether this code is correct or, if not, what's wrong with it. The one thing we can say for sure is that it leaks the memory allocated from `malloc` because there's no matching free and it does not return a pointer. But beyond that, we can only guess.

Comment: Unrelated: Please make it a habit to use *trailing* newline in your `printf` call. When `stdout` (which is the `FILE *` where `printf` writes) is connected to a console or terminal, it will be *line buffered*. That means the output will be actually written when you print a newline. By using a leading newline, you print the *previous* line, not the current line. This can lead to misleading output when using `printf` for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `DocTep` routine, you won't know in advance how many items you need to read. (So where is the `n` parameter coming from?)

If all you need to do is print the even values that were found in `infile`, you don't need to worry about managing the memory for `**p` or storing the values.  You can use a `while` loop that terminates when you reach end-of-file (which the `feof()` routine can tell you), or use the return value of `fscanf` to tell when there are no more values left to read.